# I can't use '\n" in javascript, I don't know why it isn't work

Tags: javascript, html

As I know, writing a new line is "\n", so I tried many times but it wasn't working. This is my source code and screen shot of result

```js
var ary3 = new Array('seven','eight', 'nine');
for (var i =0; i<ary3.length ; i++){
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML += i+"'\nth element\n[enter image description here][1] : " + ary3[i]+"\n";
}
```

```html
<h1>Show me the array object's entry</h1>
<div id = 'demo3'></div>
<br>
```

Comment: `\n` creates a new line in the source code, not in the HTML parsed page.
`<br />` creates the newline in the HTML page. Use both if you want your code to be clean.

Comment: Would `<p> this is \n newline</p>

Comment: you can use tag `<pre>` instead of `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the newline from JS will be rendered as plain space. HTML is responsible for new line showing, but HTML will not pay attention to simple new line in text. You can check your HTML using developer's tools. You will see that JS made new lines:
[derveloper tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj9MA.png)

To make new line work, you should add `<br />` tag

```js
var ary3 = new Array('seven','eight', 'nine');
for (var i =0; i<ary3.length ; i++){
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML += i+"'<br/>\nth element<br/>\n[enter image description here][1] : " + ary3[i]+"<br/>\n";
}
```

```html
<h1>Show me the array object's entry</h1>
<div id = 'demo3'></div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace is generically collapsed to at most a single space in HTML. Example

```html
<div>a
b        c</div>
```

Will appear as just `a b c`

You have a few options

1. Use `pre`

   ```
   <pre>a
   b</pre>
   ```

   Will appear as

   ```
   a
   b
   ```
2. Use `white-space: pre;` CSS on your div

   ```
    <div style="white-space: pre;">a
    b</div>
   ```

   Will break line breaks
3. Insert `<br/>` for `\n' as in

   ```
    var someString = "a\nb\nc";
    someElement.innerHTML = someString.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
   ```

As for your specific example of looping you also have the option to insert separate elements

```js
function insertDivWithText(parent, text) {
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
   parent.appendChild(div);
}

var demo3 = document.querySelector("#demo3");
var ary3 = ['seven','eight', 'nine'];
for (var i = 0; i < ary3.length ; ++i) {
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   insertDivWithText(demo3, i + "th element");
   insertDivWithText(demo3, "[enter image description here][1] : " + ary3[i]);
}
```

```html
<h1>Show me the array object's entry</h1>
<div id = 'demo3'></div>
<br>
```

Also note that using `.innerHTML` with user data is likely going to expose you to scripting vulnerabilities. Consider using `document.createTextNode` or `element.textContent` or `element.innerText`

Answer (score 1):

You are writing HTML, DOM, so you have to use `<br>` tag, not newline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a HTML new line, use `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

Html code for new line is `<br>`.

As in:

```
document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML += i+"'nth element<br>[enter image description
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is **html**. In html, use the **`<br />`** tag to break the line.